# how to get ipv4 in servlet req.getRemoteAddr() using Tomcat 9

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security

i want ipv4(127.0.0.1) but i am getting 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

Please any one can suggest me for how to get ipv4 using Tomcat 9

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We get IPV6 as default when we use Tomcat Version 8.1.x or latest.
For resolve IPV6 Issue from tomcat latest version. For getting IPV4 just we have to add following line into TomcatServerHome → bin → catalina.bat file add line at top
Solution (for Windows OS):

set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"